# How to populate many config files with same value(s)

Tags: linux, bash, configuration, variable, etc

I have many programs and all of them have some identical values in their config files (most, if not all, of which are in `/etc`).

Let's say it is hostname, which is stored in the config files of Apache, Postfix, SQL, clamAV, whatever...
Sometimes I need to change those values. What I do now is to edit all those files and find&replace the previous value with the new one.

I would like to change it in one place, and set all those files properly.
I thought about bash's `export` variable, `source` command or something similar; however, since the config files are not executable, I don't think it will work.

What would be the recommended method?

Comment: You will have to first MAP, all parameters in ALL config files. Some of them could be `host=` or `hostname=` or `name=`, some config files use `;` as comment, others use `#`. What you are trying to do, will require some sort of value mapping that will not be trivial enough to show in one answer...

Comment: Configuration management is typical, where you would template or otherwise mangle all those files using a `hostname` variable or whatnot set somewhere in the configuration management. However, there is no best way to do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Obviously, you must identify all the parameters that you want to manage,
and all locations where they appear. 
<sub>(Duh.)</sub> 
You knew that already.

Here’s an approach that might get you started on the right track:

1. Choose a character string that will never, ever,
   appear in one of the configuration files. 
   (That makes it sound like you *must* get it right on the first try. 
   That’s not really true; if you choose a string (for example, `@@`)
   and you later need to use that string in one of the files, you can fix it. 
   You’ll just have to redo a lot of this setup.)

   For example, a long time ago, Unix had a version control system
   called the Source Code Control System (SCCS);
   it used the string `@(#)` as a string
   that would never appear naturally in a file. 
   As far as I know, SCCS isn’t in use any more (at least, not much),
   so it should be safe to use `@(#)`. 
   Or you could use something like `!user2461440?`,
   or whatever your real name is. 
   You could include control character(s);
   e.g., <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd>.
2. Choose a naming convention for parameter placeholders. 
   This could be something simple and straightforward
   like `@(#){HOSTNAME}`, `@(#){IP}`, `@(#){GATEWAY}`, etc.
3. Create template versions of all your configuration files,
   like `apache.template`, etc. 
   Edit those templates to replace all occurrences
   of the parameters you want to manipulate
   with their corresponding parameter placeholders
   (from the previous paragraph). 
   You should put these (and the following) in a safe, out-of-the-way place,
   like a subdirectory of `/root`.
4. Write a script like this:

   ```
   HOST=Zanzibar
   IP=10.11.12.42
       ︙
   LOG=/var/log/lumber
       ︙

   fullpath[apache]=/etc/apache.conf
   fullpath[postfix]=/etc/postfix/configuration
       ︙

   for file in apache postfix …
   do
       path=${fullpath[$file]}
       sed -e "s/@(#){HOSTNAME}/$HOST/g" \
           -e "s/@(#){IP}/$IP/g" \
                      ︙
           -e "s|@(#){LOG}|$LOG|g" \
                      ︙
           "$file.template" > "$path.new"  &&
           mv "$path" "$path.bak"          &&
           mv "$path.new" "$path"
   done
   ```

   Observe that the subcommand that replaces `@(#){LOG}` with `$LOG`
   uses a different delimiter (`|`), because the `$LOG` value contains `/`s. 
   Note that, therefore,
   the `@(#)` string must not contain this delimiter (`|`). 
   (And, of course, it must not contain the standard (`/`) delimiter.)
5. Arrays (e.g., `fullpath[apache]`) don’t work in all shells. 
   If you don’t have bash or another shell that supports arrays,
   the script will need to be adapted to simulate or work around them.
6. You might need to add `chown` and `chmod` commands to the script
   to set the system attributes of the files correctly. 
   Or, if you’re really *really* sure
   that you’ve gotten the script working correctly,
   you can modify it to overwrite the files in place, as in

   ```
       sed  …      > "$path"
   ```

   thus retaining the inode and its attributes,
   and not use the `mv` command or the `.new` and `.bak` files.
7. When you want to change one of the parameters
   that you’ve chosen to automate, edit the corresponding assignment statement
   (e.g., `HOST=Wonderland`) at the beginning of the script. 
   If you don’t want to have to edit the script,
   break the script into two files:
   one that contains the parameter values (`HOST=…`, `IP=…`, etc…)
   and one that does all the handling of the configuration files. 
   The second script would `source` the first one to get the parameter values. 
   That way, when a parameter value changes,
   you need to edit only the (script) file that contains the values,
   and not the main script.
8. Be sure not to manually edit the files in place,
   as those changes will be overwritten the next time
   you run the parameterization script. 
   Instead, edit the corresponding template file and re-run the script. 
   You might want to put comments in the files to remind you of this. 
   (If you don’t like the idea
   of regenerating all of the configuration files
   for a change that affects only one of them,
   you can modify the script
   so it has the capability to regenerate only selected file(s).)

Comment: Yes, this is what I want to achieve. Regarding changing files in place, I will not be able to use "templating system" anymore, I will need to change full `name=value`. Regarding manual edit, I can always edit template file and run this script again. Thanks

Comment: I’m glad you find this to be useful. (1) I don’t understand what you’re saying about “I will not be able to use "templating system" anymore, I will need to change full `name=value`.”; perhaps you don’t fully understand what I’m suggesting. (2) “Regarding manual edit, …” — yes, that was what I meant. I have edited the answer to clarify that.

Comment: My bad, obvious mistake, I understood "in place" incorrectly - that you can put placeholders directly in the config file, not in the template. Then after first run it will not work again. What you meant by "in place" is without copying files back and forth.